# Getting unexpected token error when try to script tag dynamically with dynamic script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Goal: Need to create multiple trigger functions dynamically for different id_numbers

I am trying to create a script tag with dynamic code but I am getting below errors

I am getting $window is not defined if I try to write below code

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var script1 = document.createElement('script');
        script1.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        
        //script1.text ="$(document).ready(function() {"+
        script1.text = "$window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {"+
            "'id_number':{"+
                '"triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {'+
                    'jQuery("#submitBug-id_number").click(function(e) {'+
                        'e.preventDefault();'+
                        'showCollectorDialog();'+
                '   }); '+
            '}'+
        '}'+
            '}';
document.body.appendChild(script1);
});
```

And I have tried with different method than getting unexpected token '}'

```
    script1.innerHTML = "$(document).ready(function() {";
    script1.innerHTML = "$window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {";
        script1.innerHTML = "'id_number' :{";
        script1.innerHTML = "'triggerFunction': function(showCollectorDialog) {";
        script1.innerHTML = "jQuery('#submitBug-id_number').click(function(e) {";
        script1.innerHTML = "e.preventDefault();";
        script1.innerHTML = "showCollectorDialog();";
        script1.innerHTML = "});";
        script1.innerHTML = "},";
        script1.innerHTML = "fieldValues: {";
        script1.innerHTML = "fullname:"+ userName+",";
        script1.innerHTML = "email: "+email+",";
        script1.innerHTML = "recordWebInfo: '1',";
        script1.innerHTML = "recordWebInfoConsent: ['1']";
        script1.innerHTML = "}";
        script1.innerHTML = "}";
        script1.innerHTML = "}";*/
        script1.innerHTML = "});";
document.body.appendChild(script1);
```

Please help to write a code dynamically under script tag

Comment: well, what should `$window` be? `$(window)` perhaps?

Comment: In the second attempt, `script1.innerHTML` is overwitten 18 times. so the final result is `<script>});</script>`